# Problems with inheritance of static variables in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, static-members

I have three classes I can't modify. In short, I have a class Program, and other two classes, ProgramClient and ProgramServer, inheriting from Program. The class Program has a static variable.

Until now, I ran ProgramClient and ProgramServer in two different applications, without any problem.
Now I need to run the two classes inside the same application. Doing this, they share the static variable of their parent class, and so bad things happen.

How can I keep the two classes in their own "context" (JVM?) in order to ensure that the static variable is used by only one of the children classes?

Comment: run each one in a separate VM? what's the problem with that ?

Comment: I think your OO-concept/design is not properly thought through at this point. If 2 classes inherit from a superclass, you always have to apply the is-a-rule (seems to be the case, judging from your classnames) but if you have static fields inside the superclass, they are ought to be the same in all subclasses.
The best thing would be moving the static field into the subclasses and not inherit it. If the subclasses shall have different values in this variable, then inheriting it from a superclass is the wrong way of designing it

Comment: Doesn't that kinda' go against the point of static variables?

Comment: @MuhammadHamed Yes that's what I thought would be the right thing to do, but I don't know how to do that because the two classes are part of the same application (eclipse project). Could you exlplain me how to do that?

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu I agree with you but, as I wrote, I can't modify the classes

Answer (score 1):

Static variables, by definition cannot be overridden or duplicated between classes.

However the two classes can be separated by using two separate class loaders, that are not chained.  This is exactly how J2EE containers provider separation between web applications.

In other words, you will load the base class `Program` into the JVM twice, and sandbox them apart.  Thus giving each separate 'program' their own instance.  More can be learnt about class loaders [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html).

Here is a very simple example bootstrap program.  Make sure that the code for `ProgramClient` and `ProgramServer` are NOT on the system classpath when you start the `java` command.  You will also need to change the url to the jar file which does contain the target program code.

```
public class Bootstrap  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        URLClassLoader cl1 = new URLClassLoader(
                new URL[] {
                        new URL("file:///client.jar")
                },
                Bootstrap.class.getClassLoader()

        );

        URLClassLoader cl2 = new URLClassLoader(
                new URL[] {
                        new URL("file:///server.jar")
                },
                Bootstrap.class.getClassLoader()
        );

        invokeAsync(cl1, "a.b.c.ProgramClient");
        invokeAsync(cl2, "a.b.c.ProgramServer");
    }

    private static void invokeAsync(final ClassLoader cl, final String fqn, final String...progArgs) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Class p1 = cl.loadClass(fqn);
                    Class argType = String[].class;

                    Method m = p1.getMethod("main", argType);

                    m.invoke(null, (Object) progArgs);
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example of what I should write before I call ProgramClient.run() and ProgramServer.run() to obtain this effect?

Comment: @ssnape I have added a simple example.  Be warned that it will be sensitive to the environment that you run it in, specifically the system class path.  But it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: thank you your answer is very clear. But I still have problems, I suppose because  `ProgramClient` and `ProgramServer` use a static member of a third class, `Common`. Could you please explain me what should I do to deal with that?

Comment: @ssnape if you configure the class loaders to not share the third class, then that third class will be loaded twice.  And thus will not conflict.  Your problem is most likely to do with the class path, make sure that none of the classes from either program are on it.  Only the bootstrap program should be.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inheritance or override of static method or variable because there is only one reference for it in all the program. That the aim if static.
Maybe you have to create a context class which is instantiate for each program class.